# Python Error - TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable

Tags: python

I'm creating a chess game but I'm having a problem with my code. I have two files, the chess engine file (ChessEngine.py):

```
class GameState():
def __init__(self):
    # 8x8 2d board, each element has 2 characters.
    self.board = [
        ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
        ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
        ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
        ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
        ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]]
    self.whitetoMove = True
    self.moveLog = []

def makeMove(self, move):
    self.board[move.startRow][move.startCol] = "--"
    self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceMoved
    self.moveLog.append(move)
    self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove

def undoMove(self):
    if len(self.moveLog) != 0:
        move = self.moveLog.pop()
        self.board[move.startRow][move.startCol] = move.pieceMoved
        self.board[move.endRow][move.endCol] = move.pieceCaptured
        self.whitetoMove = not self.whitetoMove

def getValidMoves(self):
    return self.getAllPossibleMoves()

def getAllPossibleMoves(self):
    moves = [Move((6, 4), (4, 4), self.board)]
    for r in range(len(self.board)):
        for c in range(len(self.board[r])):
            turn = self.board[r][c][0]
            if (turn == 'w' and self.whitetoMove) and (turn == 'b' and not self.whitetoMove):
                piece = self.board[r][c][1]
                if piece == 'p':
                    self.getPawnMoves(r, c, moves)
                elif piece == 'R':
                    self.getRookMoves(r, c, moves)
    return moves

def getPawnMoves(self, r, c, moves):
    pass

def getRookMoves(self, r, c, moves):
    pass

class Move():
ranksToRows = {"1": 7, "2": 6, "3": 5,
               "4": 4, "5": 3, "6": 2, "7": 1, "8": 0}
rowsToRanks = {v: k for k, v in ranksToRows.items()}
filesToCols = {"a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2,
               "d": 3, "e": 4, "f": 5, "g": 6, "h": 7}
colsToFiles = {v: k for k, v in filesToCols.items()}

def __init__(self, startSq, endSq, board):
    self.startRow = startSq[0]
    self.startCol = startSq[1]
    self.endRow = endSq[0]
    self.endCol = endSq[1]
    self.pieceMoved = board[self.startRow][self.startCol]
    self.pieceCaptured = board[self.endRow][self.endCol]
    self.moveID = self.startRow * 1000 + \
        self.startCol*100 + self.endRow*10 + self.endCol
    print(self.moveID)

def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Move):
        return self.moveID == other.moveID
    return False

def getChessNotation(self):
    return self.getRankFile(self.startRow, self.startCol) + self.getRankFile(self.endRow, self.endCol)

def getRankFile(self, r, c):
    return self.colsToFiles[c] + self.rowsToRanks[r]
```

and my actual game file (ChessMate.py):

```
import pygame as p
import ChessEngine

WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT//DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15
IMAGES = {}


def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK',
              'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(
            p.image.load('Chess/Images/' + piece + '.png'), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
    moveMade = False

    loadImages()
    running = True
    sqSelected = ()
    playerClicks = []

    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                location = p.mouse.get_pos()
                col = location[0]//SQ_SIZE
                row = location[1]//SQ_SIZE
                if sqSelected == (row, col):
                    sqSelected = ()
                    playerClicks = []
                else:
                    sqSelected = (row, col)
                    playerClicks.append(sqSelected)
                if len(playerClicks) == 2:
                    move = ChessEngine.Move(
                        playerClicks[0], playerClicks[1], gs.board)
                    print(move.getChessNotation())
                    if move in validMoves:
                        gs.makeMove(move)
                        moveMade = True
                    sqSelected = ()
                    playerClicks = []
            elif e.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == p.K_z:
                    gs.undoMove()
                    moveMade = True

        if moveMade:
            validMoves = gs.getValidMoves
            moveMade = False

        drawGameState(screen, gs)
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.flip()


def drawGameState(screen, gs):
    drawBoard(screen)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)


def drawBoard(screen):
    colors = [p.Color("light yellow"), p.Color("dark green")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(
                c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(
                    c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the exact error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Name/Documents/Python/AI/Chess/Chess/ChessMate.py", line 94, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Name/Documents/Python/AI/Chess/Chess/ChessMate.py", line 51, in main
    if move in validMoves:
TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable
```

I've checked other posts which say that the person who is asking the question is missing brackets somewhere for their function but I have scanned through my code numerous times and I still can't find anything

Please help, I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this part of the code:

```
if moveMade:
            validMoves = gs.getValidMoves
            moveMade = False
```

You need to change it to this:

```
if moveMade:
            validMoves = gs.getValidMoves()
            moveMade = False
```

Comment: This should just be closed as a typo. They got it right elsewhere in the script.